# jQueryにてdiv要素にキー入力を代行させる方法

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

## やりたいこと

下記のdiv要素である"down"をクリックしている間は、下矢印キーを押し続けている扱いにする方法はないでしょうか?

試す限りでは**押し続けている**判定は、**onmousedown**を使えば出来そうですが、javascriptに「**キー入力を代わりに入力させる**」方法がわかりません。

```
<div class="down">
    <h1>↓</h1>
</div>
```

どうか、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: キーを入力させて何をしたいのでしょうか？基本的にブラウザでやるべきは特定のハードウェアインターフェースに依存しない機能を実装すべきであり、そのためここでやるべきことはキーを入力させ続けるのではなくて、キーを入力させ続けることで実現したいことの実装を考えるべきかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla.org の MDN Web Docs に解説があります。

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#auto-repeat_handling

が、キーを押し続けた場合の扱いは、ブラウザによって異なるようです。
あまり試す人もいないのでしょう、古い記事が目立ちます。最近のバージョンではどうなっているか、一度検証されるのがよいと思います。

http://shain.blog.conextivo.com/2007/03/javascript.html